# Use the base-class virtual method

Tags: c++

Starting from this code:

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual void foo(){....}
};
class Derived{
public:
    void foo(){....}
};
```

If `d` is a `Derived` object, can I in some way invoke the foo method defined in the Base class for this object?

*Edit:* i mean from the outside, such that `d.foo()` binds to Base::foo()

Comment: Yes, i forgot to specify. From the outside.

Comment: @Aslan986: Do you *really* need to do this? Do you *really*, *really* need to do this? In many cases it is quite a bad idea to force the call to execute a particular *override*... you might lead to unwanted results, broken invariants...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: i'm sure you are right. It seems a bad idea to me too. I'm just studying C++ and I want to understand what I can do and what i cannot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify it explicitly in the call.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
public:
    virtual void foo(){
      std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    }
};
class Derived : public Base{
public:
    void foo(){
      std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;

    }
};

int main()
{
  Derived d;
  d.Base::foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does answer the question and is correct, but I still feel like if you have to do this, something is very wrong.

Comment: @JohnDibling I just went through the other answers and have to agree. There is something wrong but I have been in situations with legacy code that required something like that, so I left out the word of advice. Having the ability to call a function that way should never be part of any design.

Answer (score 6):

Just qualify the call (Assuming that `Derived` actually inherits from `Base`, which in your code it doesn't):

```
Derived d;
d.Base::foo();
```

Now, while this is doable, it is also quite questionable. If the method is virtual, it is meant to be overridden and users should not call a particular override, but the *final-overrider*, or else they risk breaking class invariants all the way through.

Consider that the implementation of `Derived::foo` did some extra work needed to hold some invariant, if users call `Base::foo` that extra work would not be done and the invariant is broken, leaving the object in an invalid state.

Comment: +1 this is still correct according to the parameters of the question, but better because it addresses what is likely a mess.

Answer (score 3):

To call it from outside code, you can still explicitly qualify the name in the call:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct base { 
    virtual void do_something() { std::cout << "Base::do_something();\n"; }
};

struct derived : public base { 
    virtual void do_something() { std::cout << "derived::do_something();\n"; }
};

int main() {

    derived d;

    d.base::do_something();
    return 0;
}
```

If you're using a pointer to the object, you'd change that to `d->base::do_something();`.